# What is the most pythonic way to check if a variable is not None?

Tags: python

When I want to check if an object `x` is not None, I can either use

```py
if x:
    do_something()
```

or

```py
if x is not None:
    do_something()
```

The first variant *feels* more pythonic but I think the second variant is easier to read. What is the consensus here?

Comment: The two are not equivalent. The first checks for `is None, or empty, or 0, or False, or...`

Comment: `if x:` would do anything Falsy, not just None

Comment: @PaulM. You're right. According to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), "beware of writing `if x` when you really mean `if x is not None` -- e.g. when testing whether a variable or argument that defaults to None was set to some other value."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two have a different meaning, the first one won't be triggered by most falsy objects (`''`, `False`, `0`, etc.), the second will. So the logic is different. If you really care about not being `None`, use the second one.

```
x = False

if x:
    print('one')
if x is not None:
    print('two')
```

output:

```
two
```